# Bash script to monitor file change and execute command

Tags: bash, osx

I have a folder with a bunch of subfolders, these folders have `asciidoctor` formated files with `.adoc` extension.

Every time I made changes to files (which is often) I need to run

```
asciidoctor -q filename.adoc
```

to compile it into HTML format.

I am trying to automate the process. so far I have come with this using [entr](http://entrproject.org/):

```
ls *.adoc | entr asciidoctor -q *.adoc
```

but only works with existing folder not for subfolders. I have tried this variation, but it doesn't work:

```
find . -name '*.adoc' | entr asciidoctor -q *.adoc
```

Any ideas how I could implement this automate process for all the subfolders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Search for '*.adoc' files
2. Test if filename.adoc is newer than filename.html
3. if so, run asciidoctor on it

   ```
   find . -name '*.adoc' | while read FILE; do [ "${FILE}" -nt "${FILE%adoc}html" ] && asciidoctor -q "${FILE}" ; done
   ```

or put in a script:

```
#! /bin/bash
find . -name '*.adoc' | while read FILE; do
    if [ "${FILE}" -nt "${FILE%adoc}html" ]; then
        asciidoctor -q "${FILE}"
    fi
done
```

The one-line or the script can be run from crontab each minut:

```
crontab -e
```

add a line

```
* * * * * /home/joe/update_adoc.bash
```

Comment: I get this error when running manually to test: 
`./auto.sh: line 3: [: too many arguments`

Comment: Yes, if you have spaces in your filenames you will see that. I have added " to the above script to handle that.

Comment: It Works! While the other answers were noble and interesting ideas. This was relatively simple, easy for me to understand and actually work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Before you starts to make changes I'd offer you to make timestamp, e.g

```
touch time.stamp.file
```

After editing you can find all changed files by

```
find . -name '*.adoc' -newer time.stamp.file -exec asciidoctor -q {} +
```

Comment: Awesome but I would still have to run it manually after each change and would I have to create a new `time.stamp.file` when a create a new file in one of the subdirectories? I was hoping to have someone thing that runs in the background looking for file changes and automatically runs the command.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the opensource tool `monit`!

Let's add the following to `/etc/monit.conf`:

```
check file test with path /path/tp/test
    if changed checksum then exec "/bin/bash /path/to/script.sh" as uid a_user_id and gid a_group_id
```

We should make sure that the user with `a_user_id` as `id` has sufficient privileges to 
`/path/to/test` file and 
read, execute privileges to `/path/to/script.sh`
    
When we change `monit.conf`
then as root:

```
monit reload
```

to get the changes to the `monit daemon`

```
watch monit status
```

can show changes in `monit` report when an event is triggered

For instance in this example
when we change the contents of `/path/to/test` file
the /path/to/script.sh script will be invoked

By default `monit` wakes up every 30 seconds and does the configured checks

To check for a new file added to a directory or a file in a directory changing:

```
check directory test2 with path /path/to<br/>
      if changed timestamp then exec "/bin/bash /path/to/script.sh" as uid a_user_id and gid a_group_id
```

I believe that this configuration can be easily updated to fit your application's needs!